# Can't run ghci in Terminal

Tags: haskell, terminal, ghci

every time I type ghci into the terminal or a command I would execute through ghci it tells me `zsh: command not found: ghci`.
I'm super new to this and don't really know what to do?
Commands like cd and so on that are for the items on my Mac work just fine.

Comment: Try running `ghc`, if it doesn't work, too, try to install ghc (`sudo apt-get install ghc`). Edit: You are on MacOS? Try `brew install ghc`

Comment: Dumb question: Did you install GHC?

Comment: @JCWasmx86 tried that but it didn't work

Comment: @vivianalxx What did you try? Running GHC or installing GHC?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Yes I did, I had also used ghci all semester but it stopped working or finding it since about a week now - should I try to uninstall and reinstall it? (we're using it for a course in Haskell)

Comment: Did you recently switch from bash to zsh, possibly with an upgrade to macOS? Was the PATH entry for it only in your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I think that's it! Do you maybe know what I could do to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like `bash` was your shell when you installed GHC, but Apple later switched you to `zsh`. The problem is that it was only added to your path for `bash`. Look for a line in `~./bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` that looks something like this:

```
[ -f "${GHCUP_INSTALL_BASE_PREFIX:=$HOME}/.ghcup/env" ] && source "${GHCUP_INSTALL_BASE_PREFIX:=$HOME}/.ghcup/env"
```

It might not look quite like that, but the important part is the reference to `.ghcup/env`. Once you find that line, copy it and add it to the end of `~/.zshrc`. Then restart your shell and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the GUI version of it.

Open Ghcup GUI with the command

> ghcup tui

You would notice something like this

GCHUP GUI:

[image: GCHUP GUI]

For me when the `ghc` or `ghci` command was not working, there was a single tick beside GHC option.
Go to that option and press **s** to set. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could try wirte . ~/.ghcup/env in the ~/.zshrc file. Another thing is restarting the terminal.