# -bash: ghci: command not found (Haskell interactive shell, Haskell installation )

Tags: bash, haskell, path, macos-mojave, haskell-platform

edit : I ended up upgrading to macOS Catalina yesterday and replacing bash with zsh. One thing that should be noted is that the `stack`command worked previously, but despite all the tinkering not `ghci`
After deleting all the files that had anything to do with Haskell, I retried running `curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://get-ghcup.haskell.org | sh`
This second time there was an error with the command line tools so I had to install them manually with `xcode-select --install`. After rerunning the curl, I added the path to the environmental file to my zsh profile manually with :
`. "$HOME/.ghcup/env"\`
`echo '. $HOME/.ghcup/env' >> "$HOME/.zshrc"`
Here is the content of the env file :`export PATH="$HOME/.cabal/bin:/Users/agnel/.ghcup/bin:$PATH"`
Now everything seems to be working (I never reinstalled stack, but I think I might leave that to the side while I learn the basics of the language).

I installed the Haskell Platform yesterday but am having a hard time getting it to work correctly.

The firsts steps I did are:

1. curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh
2. curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://get-ghcup.haskell.org | sh

On step 1. the instructions said to append `/Users/.../.local/bin` the PATH variable (which I did in `/etc/paths`. On step 2, the script was supposed to pop up a dialog box (and didn't) when installing the necessary command line tools. It also said to rerun the script once complete (which I did). The script also said I should adjust my PATH variable, and source `/Users/.../.ghcup/env` in my shell configuration. It asked to this automatically but failed having not found the `~/.bashrc` File. (I read that on Mac in contrary to linux, only `.bash_profile` is loaded upon opening of a terminal window so I adjusted the path variable there manually. I've spent forever messing around with the path variables and every time I try and run "$ ghci" I get the same `-bash: ghci: command not found` error message. If anyone has a solution to this problem I would be very grateful for an answer. If not, could someone with a working distribution of Haskell on their computer show me what their path variables look like?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to just do `export PATH=$PATH:/dir/to/ghci` ? if you echo $PATH and type which ghci (prior to the other steps) does it work?

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the value of $PATH and show us the changes you've made to your config files?

Answer (score 8):

A simple solution would just be to `restart your terminal` and you are good to go.

Answer (score 7):

After installing the Haskell platform for the first time on a new mac with Catalina, I also got

```
~> ghci
zsh: command not found: ghci
```

What worked in my case was to use, instead of the plain `ghci`,

```
stack ghci
```

To get back the familiar behaviour, I created in my homedirectory a file named `.zshrc` containing

```
alias ghci='stack ghci'
```

If you open a new terminal, this file will automatically be executed.

I'd be interested to know if there is another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the `ghcup` command is working or not.

1. If not, make sure the `.zshrc` file has command for execution of ghcup. It should look something like this -

> [ -f "/Users/myusername/.ghcup/env" ] && source "/Users/myusername/.ghcup/env" # ghcup-env

- If the file exists, simply restarting terminal will work.
- If it is still not working, **set GHC as default using ghcup** - follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70362395/6646339)